# Retorno errado do comando ping

Tags: c, shell, shell-script

Levando em conta que a `${parameters}` é um array que pode conter endereços IPs válidos ou não, escrevi o seguinte código:

```
  for ((i=0; i<$#; i++)); do
        eval "arg=\${$i}" 
        ping ${parameters[i]} -c1 -q &>/dev/null
        if [ $? == 0 ]
            then
            echo "ok" 
        else
            echo "fail"
        fi
    done
```

Acontece que o retorno `$?` parece sempre conter o valor `0`, mesmo quando o IP passado na `${parameters[i]}` não é válido.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: O `for` está iterando sobre o número de argumentos do script `$#`, não seria `${#parameters[@]}` para iterar sobre o `array`? Acho que o `eval...` não é necessário.

Comment: Nesse caso, não faz diferença se estamos iterando sobre os parâmetros ou sobre o array. Mas, mesmo fazendo essa alteração, o erro persiste.

Comment: O script aqui funcionou, que IP por exemplo não é válido e mesmo assim retorna "ok"?

Comment: qualquer Ip, tipo 8.8.8.asdf

Comment: O código de erro pode variar conforme o resultado do `ping`: Sucesso: 0; Sem Resposta: 1; Outros Erros: 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O código de erro retornado pelo utilitário `ping` pode variar dependendo do ocorrido:

> **Sucesso**: 0
>
> **Timed-out**: 1
>
> **Host Inalcançável**: 2

Sendo assim, segue exemplo (testado) de um script capaz de solucionar o seu problema:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP_LIST=( 0.0.0.0
          255.255.255.255
          xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
          127.0.0.1
          172.217.29.46
          191.239.213.197
          17.172.224.47
          198.175.116.54 )

for ((i = 0; i < ${#IP_LIST[@]}; i++)); do

    ping -q -c1 "${IP_LIST[i]}" &>/dev/null

    case "$?" in
        '0') STATUS="OK" ;;
        '1') STATUS="TIMEOUT" ;;
        '2') STATUS="INALCANCAVEL" ;;
          *) STATUS="ERRO" ;;
    esac

    echo "IP: ${IP_LIST[i]} [${STATUS}]"

done
```

Saída:

```
IP: 0.0.0.0 [OK]
IP: 255.255.255.255 [INALCANCAVEL]
IP: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx [INALCANCAVEL]
IP: 127.0.0.1 [OK]
IP: 172.217.29.46 [TIMEOUT]
IP: 191.239.213.197 [TIMEOUT]
IP: 17.172.224.47 [TIMEOUT]
IP: 198.175.116.54 [TIMEOUT]
```

Um método mais confiável e robusto para solucionar o seu problema seria por meio da taxa de disponibilidade de cada IP da lista.

Segue exemplo capaz de calcular a taxa de disponibilidade dos IPs de uma lista:

```
#!/bin/bash

IP_LIST=( 8.8.8.8
          127.0.0.1
          10.1.1.19
          172.217.29.46
          191.239.213.197
          17.172.224.47
          198.175.116.54 )

for ((i = 0; i < ${#IP_LIST[@]}; i++)); do

    PCKT_LOSS=$(ping -q -c5 "${IP_LIST[i]}" | grep -oP '\d+(?=% packet loss)')

    echo "IP: ${IP_LIST[i]} [Disponibilidade: $[100 - ${PCKT_LOSS}]%]"

done
```

Saída:

```
IP: 8.8.8.8 [Disponibilidade: 0%]
IP: 127.0.0.1 [Disponibilidade: 100%]
IP: 10.1.1.19 [Disponibilidade: 100%]
IP: 172.217.29.46 [Disponibilidade: 0%]
IP: 191.239.213.197 [Disponibilidade: 0%]
IP: 17.172.224.47 [Disponibilidade: 0%]
IP: 198.175.116.54 [Disponibilidade: 0%]
```

Espero ter ajudado!